# how to get height and width of layout in run time?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

in this image, how to get the height and width of the red box as shown in image 
how to find in run time,not in XML file

Comment: You can use getLayoutParams of the red layout. There you have options to get the height/width margin etc.

Comment: i'm having two layouts one is top other one is red box in that red box i wont to display a list view. plz tell me how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make ListView as a child view of Red Layout. You don't need height/width runtime to achieve this. Simply create listview inside red layout in layout.xml and give fill_parent as layout_height and layout_width.

For Ex :

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/redLayout">
  <ListView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [View docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) on the Android SDK site.  They explain the different sizes, copied ver batim here:

> Size, padding and margins
>
> The size of a view is expressed with a width and a height. A view
>   actually possess two pairs of width and height values.
>
> The first pair is known as measured width and measured height. These
>   dimensions define how big a view wants to be within its parent (see
>   Layout for more details.) The measured dimensions can be obtained by
>   calling getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight().
>
> The second pair is simply known as width and height, or sometimes
>   drawing width and drawing height. These dimensions define the actual
>   size of the view on screen, at drawing time and after layout. These
>   values may, but do not have to, be different from the measured width
>   and height. The width and height can be obtained by calling getWidth()
>   and getHeight().
>
> To measure its dimensions, a view takes into account its padding. The
>   padding is expressed in pixels for the left, top, right and bottom
>   parts of the view. Padding can be used to offset the content of the
>   view by a specific amount of pixels. For instance, a left padding of 2
>   will push the view's content by 2 pixels to the right of the left
>   edge. Padding can be set using the setPadding(int, int, int, int) or
>   setPaddingRelative(int, int, int, int) method and queried by calling
>   getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop(), getPaddingRight(),
>   getPaddingBottom(), getPaddingStart(), getPaddingEnd().
>
> Even though a view can define a padding, it does not provide any
>   support for margins. However, view groups provide such a support.
>   Refer to ViewGroup and ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams for further
>   information.